# Upgradeds to 22.04 now Brother Printer/Scanner does not work

Tags: printing, brother

I upgraded to 22.04 and printer did not work, which I could fix, but he scanner says: No connection....
B

Comment: what application/instructions are you using for the scanner? please [edit] your question with details accordingly.

Comment: The provided programme: Document Scanner 42.0. With 20.04 it worked out of the Box. I am a bit afraid of reinstalling everything from scratch: I updated without that.

Comment: I ran into the same problem with "Document Scanner". I even downloaded and installed the latest version of scanner driver from Brother (brscan4, version 0.4.11-1), it still fails to do double-sided scan from the feeder.